# Understanding point-line distance in 2 dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance2-Dimensional.html

Im trying to understand the two dimensional line distance formula from the above Link but dont really understand a part of it. The divisor is the pythagoras distance formula I believe but what is the dividend? The part above the division? Not really sure.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos how? I already did but i just dont get what the formula as the divident does.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos are they calculating the cross product there?

Comment: No. They are computing the projection of $(x_0,y_0)$ on the line $ax+by+c=0$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I understand now but why is the multiplication similar as in the cross product of two vectors?

Comment: This is connected to the fact that the cross-product of two vectors $v$ and $w$ is orthogonal to both $v$ and $w$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos wow thanks! You can add those as the answer. It really made thing clear now.

Comment: I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authors of that page computed the projection of $(x_0,y_0)$ on the line $ax+by+c=0$. Then they computed the distance from $(x_0,y_0)$ to that projection. The final result has some resemblance with the cross-product of two vectors because the cross-product of two vectors is orthogonal to each of them.